# Where does Microsoft hide the TraceDmp tool/source?

Tags: windows, winapi, logging, windows-7

This link on MSDN says it's stored in the samples directory of the Windows SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363805(VS.85).aspx

Except it isn't, and I have the latest version. Where can one go to find this code, if not the distributable tool itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TradeDmp is a canned ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) consumer.  If you are open to using C# there is sample code for ETW event consumption [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielvl/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-consume-etw-events-from-c.aspx). Otherwise, the guidelines for consuming events in native code are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363692%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Apologies if this is telling you stuff you already know, let me know if so and I will delete this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the v6.1 WinSDK it can be found here:

%programfiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Samples\WinBase\eventtrace\tracedmp

I would need to check if it's available on newer versions of the platform SDK.

Comment: Right, under WinBase I don't have eventtrace for 7.1 SDK. I am running an old version of tracedmp from W2K Resource Kit, and I'm not sure it's outputting all the data that's in the ETL file, I can't fine the CPU utilization numbers.

Comment: Looks like the 7.1 SDK no longer contains this tool. See if you can get a copy of the 6.1 SDK and get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not TraceDmp, but I found some event samples on [their github](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/340d6c8c537919663cb122d1a3cf76bed91c06f8/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/Eventing).